# Question about a substitution in an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

So studying integrals for a short duration I found this example of an equation. It goes the following way:

$\int_{-r}^r \! \sqrt{r^2-y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y. \stackrel{y=rz}{=} \int_{-1}^1 \! r^2 \sqrt{1-z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z. $

If I get this right $y$ has been substituted with $rz$. Why could this substitution be made and why could $r^2$ be extrated from the root and not just $r$ ? I think I am missing something bigger here, but I just don't get it.

If you need further context for this equation, message me.

Answer (score 3):

$r$ is extracted and then multiplied by $dy=rdz $

Comment: What rule has been used here? Substitution rule? I just know Riemann integrals. Is further knowledge required to get the logic behind this?

Comment: Just substitution. Solve your substitution for dy in terms of dz and then plug in

Comment: This is the standard rule of change of variables in integrals. $y=rz$ implies $dy = r dz$. More generally, $y=f(x)$ implies $dy = f'(x)dx$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Answer (score 1):

By pure textual substitution, then reworking,

$$\int_{y=-r}^r \! \sqrt{r^2-y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y \stackrel{y=rz}{=} \int_{rz=-r}^r \!\sqrt{r^2-(rz)^2} \, \mathrm{d}(rz){=} \int_{z=-1}^1 \!r\sqrt{1-z^2} \, r\mathrm{d}z,$$ hence the claim.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda have difficulties calculating with the Differential like that, because we never properly defined it in our course.

Comment: Like $(rz)'=rz'$, $d(rz)=r\,dz$.